# How do I call from enum?

Tags: java

I have a java code for enum.

```
public enum TruckType{
    LIGHT, MEDIUM, HEAVY, SUPER_HEAVY, TRAILER;
}
```

Now I am trying to get MEDIUM from enum.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Truck truck1 = new Truck("John Brown","9764780493","GJ67745676","Blue", 2400000.0,2019,18,TruckType.MEDIUM);
}
```

This is what I did, but it doesn't work. What would I do to get MEDIUM from enum?
I get a null value return.

This is my Truck class with the TruckTypes

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle{
    private int wheelNo;
    public TruckType classification;

    public Truck(String ownername, String telephonenumber, String chassisNum, String color, double estimatedVal, int year,
                 int wheelNo,TruckType Classification)
    {
        super(ownername, telephonenumber,chassisNum, color, estimatedVal, year);
        this.wheelNo = wheelNo;
        this.classification = classification;
```

Comment: Please understand that `"...but it doesn't work"` tells us *nothing* of use. How doesn't it work? What doesn't work? Are you seeing a compiler error message? Are you not getting the correct program behavior? Please [edit] and improve and clarify this question. For all we know your Truck constructor doesn't have this structure, but you're not showing it, so, who knows? Please go through the [help], the [ask] and the [tour] to see how to best use this site.

Comment: Note that this usage, `TruckType.MEDIUM` ***is*** correct, but again, that doesn't help you much since we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: There can a mismatch between how you have defined the constructor and how you are trying to initialize `Truck`.

Comment: I'm assuming that the problem is a "constructor cannot be applied to given types" error, and if so, the duplicate should help with the solution being for you to create a Truck constructor that accepts the parameters that you're currently passing into it. For better help, post your Truck class code and the error message, and then we can be sure that this is in fact the problem.

Comment: I added my constructor

Comment: You've got a spelling/capitalization error. The parameter should be `TruckType classification` not `TruckType Classification`.  You're currently setting the field to itself (which is null).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels understood, yeah I should have asked this question better. Thanks for that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah, that was the issue. It works now. Nth was wrong with how I called it. Thanks again. I got to go through that help center

Comment: Answered (as a community wiki). 1+ for fixing the question

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your constructor parameter here: `TruckType Classification`

```
public Truck(String ownername, String telephonenumber, String chassisNum, String color, double estimatedVal, int year,
             int wheelNo, TruckType Classification) {
    super(ownername, telephonenumber,chassisNum, color, estimatedVal, year);
    this.wheelNo = wheelNo;
    this.classification = classification;
```

Because of your capitalization of the parameter, Java sees this:

```
    this.classification = classification;
```

as really this:

```
    // remains null
    this.classification = this.classification;
```

The solution is to check your spelling/capitalization and change `TruckType Classification` to `TruckType classification`

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle{
private int wheelNo;
public TruckType classification;

public Truck(String ownername, String telephonenumber, String chassisNum, String color, double estimatedVal, int year,
             int wheelNo,TruckType Classification)
{
    super(ownername, telephonenumber,chassisNum, color, estimatedVal, year);
    this.wheelNo = wheelNo;
    this.classification = classification;
    ---
    ---
}
```

In here, `this.classification = classification;` is wrong,
 should be `this.classification = Classification;`

Could you please check.

Comment: This is not good advice and in fact is somewhat backward as you're recommending that the original poster's (op's) current code continue to go against Java naming rules, namely that class names begin with an upper-case letter and that variable, method and parameter names with a lower-case letter. Better to go with the other Community Wiki solution, to change the case of the parameter.

Comment: Did you care to read the lines and variables used? The assignment is wrong and that's what I have tried to point him out. Better you start reading queries and solutions seriously!

Comment: Yes, I carefully read the lines and the variables used. The two answers both *work*, but only one of them follows correct Java practices. Why mislead a newbie questioner when this is completely unnecessary?